# Visibility hidden to a jsp element via javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I have this snippet of jsp code:

```
<td class='sellinfo-trgt'>${sellthroughLabel}: <span></span></td>
```

And i dinamically choose via js if I want to show or not the content of the *td* element and the *span* content.

This is the js code:

```
var oSellthrough = $($(oStore).find(".sellinfo-trgt")).find("span").toArray()[0];
var sSellthrough = SELLTHROUGH_NOT_AVAILABLE_MESSAGE;

if(sSellthrough == SELLTHROUGH_NOT_AVAILABLE_MESSAGE){
    $($(oStore).find(".sellinfo-trgt")).textContent = "";
} else {
    oSellthrough.textContent = sSellthrough;
}
```

I want to set to empty string all the content of the *td* element, not only the span content, but also the *${sellthroughLabel}* in there.

How can I do this?

```
$($(oStore).find(".sellinfo-trgt")).textContent = "";
```

seems not to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly and you want to hide the whole `<td>` content, including the inner `<span>` you would have an easier time adjusting the elements visibility or display css property. You also don't lose the original content this way.

**Visibility:** Will hide the element but the space it used to be ocupying will still be there.

**Display:** setting this to 'none' will hide the element completely, as if it never was there.

Since you seem to be using Jquery, the easiest would be to just use its hide() and show() functions. These act as if display was set to none. It even remembers the previous value, so once you show() them, they go back to 'inline'or 'block' or any previous value as needed.

```
$(your_td_element).hide(); //To hide
$(your_td_element).show(); //To display again
```

I don't think there is a function to set visibility on Jquery, but you could directly acces it using css().

```
$(your_td_element).css('visibility','hidden'); //To hide
$(your_td_element).css('visibility','');       //To display again
```

By the way, Jquery does have a text() function, which does pretty much what textContent does.

```
$(your_td_element).text(''); //should delete all inner text.
```

This will delete your span though. The same way as `your_td_element.innerHTML = '';` would. Which is why I advised to use visibility. But If you are sure that is what you want to do, then using text() instead of textContent would work.

textContent does not work cause `$($(oStore).find(".sellinfo-trgt")).textContent = "";` is trying to acces the textContent property on a Jquery wrapped object. This property is undefined (it does not exist), but does not give an error since you are assigning to it. Since it is Jquery wrapped, the correct thing to do is using text() as mentioned above, like so `$($(oStore).find(".sellinfo-trgt")).text("");`.